# ripple effect issue with materialize css

Tags: css, angular, materialize

I am using [materialize-css](https://materializecss.com/about.html) library in angular. Along with the **materialize-css** I am using [materialize-stepper](https://kinark.github.io/Materialize-stepper/) library that is based on the **materialize-css**.

MaterializeCSS uses `.waves-effect` CSS class to provide ripple effect on buttons, a tag and on all other clickables.

**materialize-stepper** also uses the `.waves-effect`. When I click on the node with `.waves-effect` class it appends a div having the ripple effect. Problem is on the next click it adds one new div with ripple effect. So it makes the clickable button or node with dark background (step 2) as this does not remove existing div.

what could be the possible issue?

[image]

Comment: Probzbly comes from the second package that depends on the first. Consider opening an issue on their repository.

Comment: yeah i will open an issue but this effect exists even if I remove materialize-stepper.

Comment: You have a double ripple with materialize ?

Comment: yes! each time i click it adds ripple effect!!

Comment: Then open an issue on their repo if it's the default behavior. If it's not, and it happens only to you, then please provide a [mcve] reproducing this issue.